# Cannot generate build files for MySQL Connector/C 6.0.2 with CMake 2.8.10.2

Tags: mysql, build, cmake, mysql-connector, cpack

I get the following two errors when I try to generate the Visual Studio 2010 build files for MySQL Connector/C 6.0.2 with CMake 2.8.10.2 on Windows 7 x64.

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CPack.cmake:395 (message):
  CPack package description file: "README" could not be found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CPack.cmake:399 (cpack_check_file_exists)
  CMakeLists.txt:371 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CPack.cmake:395 (message):
  CPack license resource file: "LICENSE.mysql" could not be found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CPack.cmake:400 (cpack_check_file_exists)
  CMakeLists.txt:371 (INCLUDE)
```

It looks to me like the problem is with CPack - but I don't really see what's going wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I built it in an external directory. The issue's gone after I built it back to MySQL Connector/C 6.0.2 folder